# asp.net cannot update database

Tags: asp.net

```
string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbnameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

myConnection.Open();
try
{
    string qry = "UPDATE customers SET firstname=@firstname WHERE cid=1";
    SqlCommand insertQuery = new SqlCommand(qry, myConnection);
    insertQuery.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstname", txtFirstname.Text));
    insertQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();

    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ee)
{

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: So there's no cid = 1 in your db?

Comment: If he was getting an Exception, it's been caught and not acted upon. @tome get rid of the try/catch just for testing.

Comment: Also if you do get an exception before closing, you will be left with an open connection with the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

A little cleanup of your code you may like to try (you should dispose IDisposable objects):

```
string ConnectionString = // ...
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE customers SET firstname = @firstname WHERE cid=1";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
    var rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific than "doesn't work" in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: What's the value of `rowsUpdated` after executing this statement?